# cannont send message through renderer process in electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am using electron to build a simple desktop app but the issue here is that whenever i try to send message to a channel named 'test' it works but similarly if i try to send message to a channel 'jest' there is no output I am using react and electron I have enabled nodeintegration here is the code

```
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200, 
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, '\\preload.js')
        },
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(
        electronIsDev
            ? 'http://localhost:3000'
            : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
    );

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})

electron.ipcMain.on('test', (event) => {
    console.log("listener is working");
    getWeekList(event);
})
```

here is what i am calling

```
console.log('preload is working');

const test = () => {
    console.log("test here");
    ipcRenderer.send('test');
}


const jest = () => {
    console.log("jest here");
    ipcRenderer.send('jest');
}


module.exports = {test, jest};
```

what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the problem was solved by moving some channel calls to the top of the main script. I don't know what was causing this but everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of [`.on()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener) is a *channel*, it's how you identify the connection between the ipcRenderer and the ipcMain. They **must be the same** in order to talk between them.

This line is looking for `"test"`, you need to make another one for `"jest"`.

```js
electron.ipcMain.on('test', (event) => {
    console.log("listener is working");
    getWeekList(event);
});

// add this one
electron.ipcMain.on('jest', (event) => {
    console.log("listener is working");
    getWeekList(event);
});
```

Comment: I have tried changing but the only test works sending a message to channel jest does not work at all

Comment: @AryanChoudhary what does your full renderer / ui / script page look like?